# How to read lines from file and split it based on comma delimited and assign variable names

Tags: linux, bash

This is what i have as input line

```
Table_name,1~2~3,U,2018-09-26 05:07:31.000000886,2018-09-26 06:49:03.003,DEPT_NBR|DIV_NBR,FARGO                              |                |916244244                                         |
||||||,FARGO||916244244|
```

```
awk -F, '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i}' file
```

and below is what it gives

```
Table_name  
1~2~3  
U  
2018-09-26 05:07:31.000000886  
2018-09-26 06:49:03.003  
DEPT_NBR|DIV_NBR  
FARGO                              |                |916244244                                         
||||||FARGO||916244244|
```

Below is expected output that i'm looking for

```
Tablename:Table_name  
Row_key:1~2~3  
CDC_FLAG:U  
INGESTION_TS:2018-09-26 05:07:31.000000886  
CDC_TS:2018-09-26 06:49:03.003  
FIELD_NAME:DEPT_NBR|DIV_NBR  
OLD_VALUES:FARGO                              |                |916244244                                          
NEW_VALUES:||||||FARGO||916244244|
```

and i want to be able to compare OLD_VALUES and NEW_VALUES and write the differences

Comment: Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Input the names in your BEGIN block.

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN { name[1] ="Tablename"; name[2]="Row_key"; etc.}
      {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print name[i] ":" $i}' file
```